# NSXMLParser with external DTD

Tags: ios, xml, cocoa, nsxmlparser

I cannot figure out how to use NSXMLParser to recognize an external DTD reference. For testing I am using the XML from an Xcode Info.plist which begins with

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
    <dict>
```

my parser is set up like this:

```
NSXMLParser *parser = [[NSXMLParser alloc] initWithData:plistData];
[parser setShouldResolveExternalEntities:YES];
[parser setDelegate:self];
[parser parse];
```

but neither of the NSXMLParserDelegate methods that deal with external entities

```
- (NSData *)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser resolveExternalEntityName:(NSString *)name systemID:(NSString *)systemID
- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser foundExternalEntityDeclarationWithName:(NSString *)name publicID:(NSString *)publicID systemID:(NSString *)systemID
```

gets called. Am I implementing this wrong? I am able to parse an internally-declared DTD, but the external one is eluding me.

Comment: Your XML doesn't have any external entities declared in it. Those have `!ENTITY` which would be defined inside the `!DOCTYPE`.

Comment: Is it the NSXMLParserDelegate's responsibility to load the DTD from that URL then?

Comment: No, the `NSXMLParser` does all of the work. The delegate is implemented by your code to be notified about various parsing events. BTW - The DTD doesn't need to be loaded to parse the XML. And the DTD is not an external entity which is why those particular delegate methods are not called for the XML you posted.

Comment: So if you want to perform DTD validation in iOS, internal DTD is the only way?